# Identification of the object of a given sentence

Tags: english, tools, grammatical-object

I am working in a project where I need to identify the object(s) of an English sentence. Is there any tool or work that can help identify the object(s) of a sentence? I will be very grateful for your help.

Comment: Presumably you're speaking of automatic recognition. There are syntactic tests for direct and indirect objecthood, but they require a native speaker in the decision loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a parser to identify objects automatically. There are a few online interfaces to natural language parsers. For example, you could use the Stanford parser ([link](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/)) and look for "dobj" to find direct objects.

Comment: It'll never be as good as a trained linguist of course! Probably less expensive than hiring a syntactician though.

Comment: For one sentence, it's not a problem. And the tests are public knowledge anyway.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the standford parser is called [Freeling](http://nlp.lsi.upc.edu/freeling/), it does a pretty good job but is a bit harder to use.